# Can not use BackgroundService as a HostedService in Program.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I am using a BackGroundService to do some tasks and those tasks include api calls and db operations so i am using a middleware and dbcontext inside this BackgroundService. I added it as a hosted service `builder.Services.AddHostedService<MyBackgroundService>();` inside my Program.cs but the problem is it does not accept it because of some singleton errors. My Program.cs :

```
using IMEAmazon.Middleware;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddScoped<Middleware>();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<IMEAmazon.Models.DBModels.imeContext>();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<MyBackgroundService>();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});


var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");

app.Run();
```

My BackgroundService:

```
public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyBackgroundService> _logger;
    private readonly Middleware _middleware;
    private readonly imeContext _context;

    public MyBackgroundService(ILogger<MyBackgroundService> logger, Middleware middleware, imeContext context)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _middleware = middleware;
        _context = context;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (IsTimeToRunTask())
            {
               
            }

            // Wait for the next iteration
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    private bool IsTimeToRunTask()
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-6);
        return (now.Hour == 20 && now.Minute == 25) || (now.Hour == 18 && now.Minute == 0);
    }
}
```

Detailed error message:

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IMEAmazon.Middleware.Middleware Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: IMEAmazon.Middleware.Middleware': Cannot consume scoped service 'IMEAmazon.Models.DBModels.imeContext' from singleton 'IMEAmazon.Middleware.Middleware'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: MyBackgroundService': Cannot consume scoped service 'IMEAmazon.Models.DBModels.imeContext' from singleton 'IMEAmazon.Middleware.Middleware'.)'**

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'IMEAmazon.Models.DBModels.imeContext' from singleton 'IMEAmazon.Middleware.Middleware'.**

When i don't use Middleware and DBContext classes inside BaackgroundService the error cleans up but i need to use them. I use .net6.0. What is that and how can i solve this?

Comment: Well, based on your scenario and description, the error arises because you're attempting to inject scoped services (Middleware and imeContext) into a singleton service (MyBackgroundService). Scoped services are designed to be created per request, while singletons exist for the entire application lifetime. This conflict causes the dependency injection container to fail. In order to the issue, you can  resolve Scoped Services Within the Background Service.

Comment: You should create and dispose another service scope inside your `ExecuteAsync` method to obtain your scoped services. And perhaps for each iteration of your loop, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When i don't use Middleware and DBContext classes inside
> BaackgroundService the error cleans up but i need to use them. I use
> .net6.0. What is that and how can i solve this?

According to your scenario and based on the shared code snippet, you are getting error because you're attempting to inject scoped services (Middleware and imeContext) into a singleton service (MyBackgroundService). Scoped services are designed to be created per request, while singletons exist for the entire application lifetime. This conflict causes the dependency injection container to fail. In order to fix the issue, you can resolve Scoped Services Within the [Background Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Let's have a look how we can implement that in practice:

```
public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyBackgroundService> _logger;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public MyBackgroundService(
        ILogger<MyBackgroundService> logger,
        IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (IsTimeToRunTask())
            {
                using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
                {
                    var middleware = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Middleware>();
                    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<imeContext>();
                    
                    _logger.LogInformation("Executing background task...");
                    
                }
            }

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    //Note:  Your ... IsTimeToRunTask() implementation will remain same
}
```

**Note:** Ensure proper management of DBContext lifetime in background services to avoid issues like connection pooling and thread safety. Consider using a separate context instance for each operation within the service.

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<Middleware>();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<IMEAmazon.Models.DBModels.imeContext>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<MyBackgroundService>();
```

**Note:** We even can use `builder.Services.AddTransient<Middleware>();` But it depends on your requirement and scenario.

However, another way could be,  you can create a new instance of imeContext directly within the MyBackgroundService. This instance is used exclusively for the background task, and no explicit scope is created. The background task uses a separate DbContext for its database operations. This also should resolve your issue.

In addition to this, carefully consider whether using middleware directly within a background service is appropriate for your architecture. Middleware is typically designed to intercept request pipeline operations. If its functionality is primarily for background tasks, it might be better to refactor it as a separate service. Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio) for additional read and example.

Answer (score 1):

Since MyBackgroundService is a singleton service and imeContext and Middleware are scope services, and in ASP.NET Core, scope services cannot be directly injected into singleton services for use, so you can try to use imeContext and Middleware as singleton services.：

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Middleware>();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<imeContext>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```

Or use ExecuteAsync through IServiceProvider in MyBackgroundService to create a scope：

```
public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MyBackgroundService> _logger;
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public MyBackgroundService(ILogger<MyBackgroundService> logger, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                if (IsTimeToRunTask())
                {
                    using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
                    {
                        var middleware = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Middleware>();
                        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<imeContext>();

                       

                    }
                }

                // Wait for the next iteration
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), stoppingToken);
            }
        }

        private bool IsTimeToRunTask()
        {
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-6);
            return (now.Hour == 20 && now.Minute == 25) || (now.Hour == 18 && now.Minute == 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Which method to use needs to be determined based on your needs.